# Get XDocument value C#

Tags: c#

I have the following `XDocument` object:

```
<Field value="&lt;MyTag&gt;BlaBla&lt;/MyTag&gt;" />
```

I want to get the value with the &lt ; &gt ; etc..What I'm tried:

```
string value = myXdocumentObject.Element("Field").Attribute("value").Value;
```

But value is `< MyTag>BlaBla< /MyTag>'` and not `&lt ;MyTag&gt;BlaBla&lt ;/MyTag& gt;`

How can i take the value?

Comment: Have you tried adding .ToString()?  seems like you're getting the unescaped version of the text.  The Escape function found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx    could help you out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is default behavior. Value property will decode escaped characters. If you want to have it encoded; you can just re-encode it with [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var value = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myXdocumentObject.Element("Field").Attribute("value").Value);
```